# Is there a way to control the Jenkins failure reason? (It's failing because of a Maven plug-in problem)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration

All my tests pass.
But, this is the reason my Build in Jenkins is failing:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar
(default-jar) on project my-project-tests: Execution default-jar of goal 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar failed: 
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one 
of its dependencies could not be resolved:
Failed to collect dependencies at 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4 -> org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.5:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.5:
Could not transfer artifact 
org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.5 from/to company-artifactory 
(http://company.jfrog.io/company/company-maven-mirror): Not authorized -> [Help 1]
```

**Is there a way to config the Jenkinsfile with this error to end with BUILD SUCCESS ?**

Comment: There is an permission problem `http://company.jfrog.io/company/company-maven-mirror): Not authorized -` ! Nothing to do with other thing. Apart from that using very old plugin version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the results of your build using `currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS/UNSTABLE/FAILURE"` and try/catch blocks around the faulty block (see [there](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218554077-How-to-set-current-build-result-in-Pipeline) for more information)

However I think you should solve this maven issue. Looking at the logs it seems that you try to reach an artifactory without proper authorization. Furthermore this artifactory seems like a fake one (company.jfrog.io/company/company-maven-mirror?). Maybe it is a copy/paste issue inside your project.

So if this artifactory exists ask for the credentials and if it doesn't maybe remove it from you pom.xml

Comment: Thanks, sounds great. I wrote the company name instead of my company's name (;